# Unable to understand the declaration of signal function in C/Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux

Firstly, I am new to C++ on Linux (touching C/C++/Linux after almost 20 years), so apologies for being naive.

I saw the use of `signal` function in the source for `showkey` program [here](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/legion/kbd/+/1.10/src/showkey.c) and went on searching for how this works. I understood how this works, but it is the declaration of signal function that I am unable to understand.

[This Page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_signal.htm) says that the `signal` function is defined as

`void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int)`

In this, I understood

- return type is `void`
- first parameter is `int` type
- second parameter is a pointer to function that accepts an `int` parameter and returns a `void`

What I am unable to understand is:

- bracket after void and before star * (in the very beginning) why this ordering of brackets?
- why `signal` method name is presented as pointer (*signal(...)?
- what does the `(int)` in the end means?

Can anyone please help me understand this.
If there is any reference to this advanced level of C pointer usage that will be much beneficial for my overall understanding and learning.

TIA.

Comment: Already closed so I can't answer, but use [cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/?q=void+%28*signal%28int%2C+void+%28*%29%28int%29%29%29%28int%29): "declare signal as function (int, pointer to function (int) returning void) returning pointer to function (int) returning void" (you have to remove the parameter names for it to work)

Comment: The `signal` function returns a pointer to the previous signal handler.  In other words the return type of the `signal` function is *"pointer to function that accepts an `int`"*, just like the second argument is a *"pointer to function that accepts an `int`"* So you pass a function pointer in, and you get one back. It's easier to see if you remove the function arguments: `void (*signal(...))(int)`